# Wrong precedence when doing a string concatenation in php

Tags: php, string, echo, string-concatenation

The code is quite simple:

```
echo 'RESP:'.$db->printList($pprofile);
```

What `db->printList($pprofile);` does is that it prints some more string. I'm basically putting the string `RESP` before the value returned by `db->printList($pprofile);`.

The problem is that the result is reversed. If `db->printList($pprofile);` returns `A`, then I always get this: `A:RESP` whereas I expect `RESP:A`.

I never have had a problem like this and I'm confused. I'm doing very similar things in many other places (with other types of inputs/outputs) in the same script with correct results. Any thoughts?

Comment: Show the code for `printList()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printList` does not return value, it prints it and thats why you have reversed order (method is executed during concatenation, value is printed, then string is concatenated with nothing returned by method and printed with `echo`).

Comment: It does not print actually. `printList` only returns a value as I described and echo prints it.

Comment: try to run it without echo, there is no other way to reverse order like you described here

Comment: @hsnm - That's not what you described. Quote: "What `db->printList($pprofile);` does is that **it prints some more string**".

Comment: @lupatus you're right. I think this is my problem. I'll try to take a closer look.